# Can't change locale: LANGUAGE is not compatible with LANG

Tags: command-line, sudo, language-support

Trying to change my locale from en_IN to ja_JP so I can get some software to work, however when i try it it gives me this error

```
[sudo] password for shadowsamurai:           
*** update-locale: Warning: LANGUAGE ("en_IN:en") is not compatible with LANG (ja_JP.utf8). Disabling it.
```

Ubuntu version: 18.04

Comment: That sounds as correct behavior to me. What's your question?

Comment: i needed to change the locale did it change it or not i'm confused

Comment: Yes, it changed the `LANG` variable. But it also disabled the `LANGUAGE` variable. You can see what it looks like by checking the contents of the file: `cat /etc/default/locale`